# Modify non-adjacent lines specified by line numbers

Tags: bash, sed

I know the line numbers in advance, and keep them in another file:

```
cat linenos
2
15
42
44
... etc
```

as you see the lines are non-adjacent so I cannt use one range for `sed`.
The goal is to modify target file lines by, say, prepending them with a marker like MARKER

Straight forward way is to call `sed` multiple times to modify each line:

```
for l in $(cat linenos)
do 
  sed -i "${l}s/^/MARKER/" target_file
done
```

which apparently will call sed multiple times.

**CAUTION**: *Not only is this approach inefficient it can also make things go wrong if the modification is other than inserting a marker like this. Any line deletion or insertion sed command like d a r, will make initial line number in linenos invalid for the next sed runs in the loop.

What would you suggest to improve/optimize that?

Sample linenos file

```
cat linenos
2
5
```

Sample target_file

```
cat target_file
line one
line two
line three
line four
line five
line six
```

Expected result of modified target_file

```
cat target_file
line one
MARKERline two
line three
line four
MARKERline five
line six
```

Possible approach i came up with is dynamically create sed scenario

```
SEDCMD=$(for l in $(cat linenos); do echo -n "${l}s/^/MARK/;" ; done)

sed -i -e "$SEDCMD" targetfile
```

@steeldriver's [below](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/570109/84561) approach shares the idea, but is more elegant and concise

Comment: I have realized that the 1st straight forward approach is faulty. Made an update on that.

Comment: Unless `MARKER` contains a newline, how are the line numbers affected?

Comment: @chepner you are right, I was influenced by my final goal which goes beyond of the scope of the example I used in my question. Corrected my note accordingly. Thank you

Comment: Maybe you should select one answer, it is expected that you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `fileN` contains the numbers of lines to be modified, and `target_file` is the text file that contain the lines to be modified. The minimum solution will require to read each file once.

## Sorted

If the file that contains the line numbers contains one number (bigger than 1) per line, is sorted and there are no repetitions, we can use:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ getline lineN <"fileN"} {
     if(NR==lineN){$0="MARKER " $0;getline lineN <"fileN"}
     }1' target_file
```

Which will keep only one line in memory (of each file) and walk both files from start to end. However once awk has processed a line, line 15 for example, it won't go back to line 12, for example. So, the file `lineN` has to be sorted (not repeated, and greater than 1) for this to work.

## Unsorted

Of course, the naive solution is that the line numbers file could be sorted `sort -nu fileN`.

But, if the list of line numbers may be unsorted (and repeated), we may use either sed , `ed` (the precursor of `sed`), or awk (later):

Convert each line in `lineN` to a sed editing command like `s/^/MARKER /`. Either shell printf or sed could do that:

```
printf '%ss/^/MARKER /\n' $(<fileN) | sed -f - target_file
sed 's#$#s/^/MARKER /#' fileN       | sed -f - target_file

{ printf '%ss/^/MARKER /\n' $(<fileN); printf '%s\n' ,p Q; } | ed -Gs target_file
{ sed 's#$#s/^/MARKER /#' fileN ; echo "w"      ; } | ed target_file
```

Note that in the last case the editing is done directly and at the original file. The last command `w` writes the modifications to file. If what is needed is to print the result then use the third option, which will print all lines.

#### awk

In awk, capture the whole `fileN` in memory and process `target_file`

```
awk '{ if(NR==FNR){
                     a[$1]=1
                  }else{
                     if(a[FNR]==1){ printf("%s","MARKER ")};
                     print 
                  }
     }' fileN target_file
```

Or, with a variable to control when the list of files with line numbers has ended:

```
awk '{ if (dofile==1) {   if(a[FNR]==1){ printf("%s","MARKER ")};
                          print
                      }else{
                          a[$1]=1
                      }
     }' fileN fileK   dofile=1   target_file
```

Note that the last version allows several files with line numbers, like `fileN` and `fileK` in the example.

Also note that the awk versions do **not** process repeated line numbers. All repeated line numbers are processed just once.

Comment: special thanks for `$(<file)` idiom

Answer (score 10):

You could use sed itself (or another text-processing utility of your choice) to turn the line numbers into sed expressions, then pass those to sed using the `-f` switch

Ex.

```
sed 's:$:s/^/MARKER/:' linenos | sed -f- -i target_file
```

This at least only calls sed *twice*.

Comment: That's great!
Do you think sorting `linenos` content will improve  the sed efficiency in case it is unsorted initially?

Comment: @Tagwint that's an interesting question - I don't know

Comment: @Tagwint - no. For each line in your target file,  `sed` will process the entire `lineos`-based script (that is, check each editing command and execute it, if applicable).

Comment: @don_crissti thanks, that makes sense indeed.

Comment: @steeldriver can you explain the first command, or at least give a name which can I can google.

Comment: @Prvt_Yadav the first command just uses `sed` to insert the string `s/^/MARKER/` at the end of each line (`$`) of the file `linenos`

Answer (score 6):

With `perl` (where GNU `sed` got `-i` from):

```
perl -pi -e '
  BEGIN{$l{0+$_}=1 while <STDIN>}
  $_ = "MARKER$_" if $l{$.}' target_file < linenos
```

We feed the list of line numbers on `perl`'s stdin. That is read in the `BEGIN` block.

For each line of input, we convert that line to a number with `0+$_`. That makes the newline character go away and also canonicalises the numbers (all of 1e0, 1, 01 become 1).

The `%l` hash table is populated with value `1` for each line number as the key.

The `target_file` is processed in the main `-p` loop where `MARKERS` is prepended to lines where the current line number (`$.`) is found in `%l` with a non-zero value.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]="MARKER"; next} {print a[FNR] $0}' linenos target_file
line one
MARKERline two
line three
line four
MARKERline five
line six
```

or to save a bit of memory:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} {print (FNR in a ? "MARKER" : "") $0}' linenos target_file
line one
MARKERline two
line three
line four
MARKERline five
line six
```

If you want "inplace" editing (same as perl and GNU sed with `-i`) use GNU awk and change `awk '...'` to `awk -i inplace '...'` and add a `print;` before the `next` statement so your `linenos` file doesn't get emptied. IMHO it's simpler to just do this with any awk (or any other UNIX tool):

```
awk 'script' linenos target_file > tmp && mv tmp target_file
```

Comment: If `linenos` contains repeated line numbers, they will be processed only once.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, using `ed` instead of `sed` to modify the `target_file` in place:

```
(while IFS= read n; do echo "${n}s/^/MARKER/"; done < linenos; echo w) |  ed -s target_file
```